# Set Theory Problem subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the sets deﬁned by the real solutions of the inequalities

$A= \{(x,y):x^2+y^4\leqslant 1\}$                $B= \{(x,y):x^4+y^6\leqslant 1\}$

Then
(A) $B\subseteq A$

(B) $A\subseteq B$

(C) Each of the sets $A-B$, $B-A$ and $A\cap B$ is non-empty

(D) none of the above.

My logic is x and y values of B will be larger than A as they are raised to higher powers (with the sum lower than 1). So, is option B the right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.

Real solutions in $A$ and $B$ will have to satisfy $x^2 \le 1$ and $y^2 \le 1$.

So $x^4 \le x^2$ and $y^6 \le y^4$.  So $x^4 + y^6 \le x^2 + y^4$.  Any element $(x,y) \in A$ must be a solution to $B$ as well, so $A \subset B$.